# How to get Column from Max of multi another columns?

Tags: database, sqlite, group-by, max, window-functions

I need to get the G value at that row contain max of max columns (H,J,J)

Below example: after group, max value of H or I or J is 170, so I need to get column value in column G is 06/25/2022 07:00:00.

I used the following query, it seems to work but returned a lot of missing values after GROUP

```
"Select C,MAX(MAX(H),MAX(I),MAX(J)) as d1,G GROUP BY C HAVING H=d1 OR I=d1 OR j=d1"
```

[image]

How do I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns the max of `H`, `I` and `J` for each `C` like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT C, MAX(MAX(H), MAX(I), MAX(J)) max
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY C
)
SELECT t.C, t.G 
FROM tablename t
WHERE (t.c, MAX(t.H, t.I, t.J)) IN (SELECT C, max FROM cte);
```

For your sample data, maybe it is more suitable to `GROUP BY B`.

Or, with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C ORDER BY MAX(H, I, J) DESC) rn
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT C, G 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Or, with `FIRST_VALUE()` window fuction:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C, 
       FIRST_VALUE(G) OVER (PARTITION BY C ORDER BY MAX(H, I, J) DESC) G
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c4e3738ee39d62705d97d54fb7f91db1).